# R chain assignment creates 'quantum entanglement' of newly-created columns, behaves unexpectedly during data.table assignment

Tags: r, data.table, assign

Quantum entanglement phrasing obviously a little tongue-in-cheek but you'll see what I mean.

If one creates multiple data.frame columns using chain assignment, those columns all behave as one later, even though they (and their parent `df`) appear normal. Observe, columns created independently:

```
library(data.table)
testdf <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
testdf$b <- as.numeric(rep(NA, nrow(testdf)))
testdf$c <- as.numeric(rep(NA, nrow(testdf)))
mergedf <- data.frame(a = 5:7, b = 1:3, c = 8:10)
setDT(testdf)
setDT(mergedf)
testdf[mergedf, on = "a", b := i.b]
testdf[mergedf, on = "a", c := i.c]
# works as expected
```

Columns created by chain assignment, which `assignOps` help and [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/assignment-in-r-slings-and-arrows/) suggest should be fine (or at least don't warn against it):

```
testdf2 <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
testdf2$c <- testdf2$b <- as.numeric(rep(NA, nrow(testdf)))
mergedf2 <- data.frame(a = 5:7, b = 1:3, c = 8:10)
setDT(testdf2)
setDT(mergedf2)
testdf2[mergedf2, on = "a", b := i.b]
# testdf2$b and $c both get mergedf2's b values
testdf2[mergedf2, on = "a", c := i.c]
# testdf2$b and $c both get mergedf2's c values, overwriting the b values
```

This doesn't seem to be documented in `assignOps`, I've not seen it mentioned anywhere, and it seems highly unintuitive that columns/values created in this way - which appears to be a simple space-saving shortcut - become bound together by a secretive pact, potentially to turn against you when your guard is down. To further underline how secret this is, if you just do the creation lines:

```
testdf <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
testdf$b <- as.numeric(rep(NA, nrow(testdf)))
testdf$c <- as.numeric(rep(NA, nrow(testdf)))
testdf2 <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
testdf2$c <- testdf2$b <- as.numeric(rep(NA, nrow(testdf)))
all.equal(testdf, testdf2) #TRUE
```

It's also true if you `setDT()` both `dfs`.

Comment: `identical(address(testdf2$B), address(testdf2$C))` is `TRUE`. hence the update by reference will change both simultaneously. you can check when base R started using the same memory for an assignment like this `testdf2$C <- testdf2$B <- `. and hence, its not quantum entanglement but its one and only

Comment: interesting, thanks. So `a <- b <- 1` will put `a` & `b` in the same memory address and thus they are the same thing thereafter? Does this seem logical and intuitive to you? (honest question, not passive aggressive). I've found sometimes there's a long chain of reasons why R behaves a certain way, but regardless of the history it can be unintuitive and behave badly. At the vest least it feels like this is something that could be added to the `assignOps` help page...

Comment: The issue is a combination of associating multiple variables names to the same address, *and then* using `data.table`'s `:=`, which specifically does assignment by reference. See `?\`:=\``. AFAIK you won't run into these issues if you use base R assignment operators like `<-` to modify your columns, because they don't assign by reference.

Comment: i think its by design. there are always tradeoffs in every situation. in this case, saving RAM but creating side effects

Comment: thanks for the input both. I was completely unaware that it's even possible to assign 2 things to the same address; hadn't really thought about memory addressing at all tbh. Data.table's `:=` says "no check is performed for duplicate assignments, i.e. if multiple values are passed for assignment to the same index, assignment to this index will occur repeatedly and sequentially" which may be alluding to this. Nonetheless I feel it would be useful to note the shared memory addressing in the help for `<-` since otherwise this can bite people.